# Hash (character) in Shared Urls for affiliate purposes is removed in Wall

Tags: facebook, url, hash

Here is the situation, am developing an ASP.Net app where the user on one of the pages has an an option to share the link on facebook. The link(s) that is formed is something like:
http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=%22http://public-test.chillisauce.co.uk/stag-weekends/bournemouth/it-s-been-emulsional~pk1055/#ccffe243%22

where the value after # is required and handled when the link is visited. That is, we need the value in a cookie after the link:
http://public-test.chillisauce.co.uk/stag-weekends/bournemouth/it-s-been-emulsional~pk1055/#ccffe243%22
is clicked.

But if the same url is used for sharing purposes under a facebook (share) button which forms the URL above, it automatically removes the # and the subsequent value. That is, when clicked, the facebook login page is opened and after successful login when the link is shared, the link appears without the:
/#ccffe243%22

part

without the hash part, meaning we cannot save the value in the cookie for further tracking purposes.

Is there any limitation set by facebook to remove the # etc. We cannot use another character fear of indexing by google etc. Can anybody help?

Here is the link to the test page with the facebook link:
(add http here): public-test.chillisauce.co.uk/stag-weekends/cambridge/
 
(click on the eMail icon in the listing below (next to More Details img). The popup has the facebook link in it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replaced # with its encoded equivalent %23.